# Extract strings values from DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

| Student | food |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | R0100000 |
| 2 | R0200000 |
| 3 | R0300000 |
| 4 | R0400000 |

I need to extract as a string the values of the "food" column of the df DataFrame when I filter the data.

For example, when I filter by the Student=1, I need the return value of "R0100000" as a string value, without any other characters or spaces.

This is the code to create the same DataFrame as mine:

```
    data={'Student':[1,2,3,4],'food':['R0100000', 'R0200000', 'R0300000', 'R0400000']}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried to select the Dataframe Column and apply str(), but it does not return me the desired results:

```
    df_new=df.loc[df['Student'] == 1]
    df_new=df_new.food
    df_str=str(df_new)

    del df_new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, first get the column.
like, `col =data["food"]` and then use `col[index]` to get respective value
So, you answer would be `data["food"][0]`
Also, you can use iloc and loc search for these.
(`df.iloc[rows,columns]`, so we can use this property to get answer as, `df.iloc[0,1]`)
`df.loc[rows, column_names]` example: `df.loc[0,"food"]`

Comment: Thank you !
Im new to Python and I have a lot to learn. Hope to someday see the things easily as you do :), but I have to practice a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

`s = df[df.Student==1]['food'][0]`

`s.strip()`